Bind rows and perform left join from a set piped lists using tidyverse method
Here is the dput() deconstruction of the data.
library(tidyverse)

structure(list(L1 = c("Age Class", "Age Class", "Age Class", 
"Age Class", "Gender", "Gender", "Gender", "Age Class", "Age Class", 
"Age Class", "Gender", "Gender", "Age Class", "Age Class", "Age Class", 
"Gender"), L2 = c("Older Youth", "Older Youth", "Younger Youth", 
"Younger Youth", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Younger Youth", 
"Older Youth", "Older Youth", "Male", "Male", "Younger Youth", 
"Older Youth", "Older Youth", "Female"), scr = c(0.78125, 0.90625, 
0.90625, 0.6875, 0.875, 0.78125, 1, 0.65625, 0.75, 0.59375, 0.8125, 
0.75, 0.65625, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.75)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")



I want to perform median and standard error as overall statistics

Perform again median and standard error by grouping L1 and L2

Perform wilcoxon test within L1 since it contains 2 factors for each group.

Merge these three lists: a) by bind_rows() from the results of step1 and step2. Then left_join() the p.values (step3) with the dataset.


Desired end result will look like the picture below:

I have tried creating a list() for each of the steps within dplyr but handling list() i.e. selection or filtering in dplyr or piped environment is cumbersome. However, the following chunk works but I want to reduce list handling as much as possible. Especially the second half of the code I think can be reduced or simplified.
df %>% 
  list(
    a={.} %>% mutate(L1="All", L2="All") %>% summarise(mdn=median(scr), se=(sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr))), .by = c(L1, L2)),
    b={.} %>% summarise(mdn=median(scr), se=(sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr))), .by = c(L1, L2)),
    c={.} %>% summarise(pv= wilcox.test(scr~L2)$p.value, .by = L1)) %>% 
  list(
    d= {.} %>% keep(names(.) %in% c('a','b')) %>% bind_rows(), #Reduce codes from this line
    c= {.} %>% pluck("c")) %>% 
  keep(names(.) %in% c('c','d')) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by="L1") #to this line

Would like to know whether there is any scope of nesting dataframe. Any purrr::map() way of reducing the scripts/texts.

There's three different operations with different set of vars, so purrr::map() may have nothing to offer. What's the motivation to do this with a list instead of just bind_rows( "a", left_join( "b", "c" ))?

Thank you @AdrianoMello for the response. That's how I want it to be in theory but it doesn't work with list() object. FYI, there are actually 4 nested objects/elements produced after first operation. One is dataset and the other 3 are a,b, and c.

I think my question was not clear (sorry for that). I mean: why do you want to use a list when bind_rows( a left_join(b, c)) delivers the expected output (It worked here)? There will be others datasets as input to these operations?

I actually wanted one single piece of piped code to do everything. I usually avoid creating to many objects in global environment. However, found the solution and answered in the thread.

Using %$% instead of %>% (from magrittr) will keep the data independent and not ingest first argument into the pipe and therefore just doing %$% left_join(bind_rows(.$a, .$b), .$c) just like the regular dataframe way will suffice.
library(magrittr)
df %$% 
  list(
    a={.} %>% mutate(L1="All", L2="All") %>% summarise(mdn=median(scr), se=(sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr))), .by = c(L1, L2)),
    b={.} %>% summarise(mdn=median(scr), se=(sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr))), .by = c(L1, L2)),
    c={.} %>% summarise(pv= wilcox.test(scr~L2)$p.value, .by = L1)
    ) %$% 
  left_join(bind_rows(.$a, .$b), .$c) 


I really liked your own solution and will take note of it!

Per Adriano's point, it seems to me like the easiest way to do this (by far) would just be to do these three very different operations separately, then bind the outputs together:
# Overall statistics
out_1 <- df %>%
  summarize(
    mdn = median(scr),
    se = sd(scr) / sqrt(n())
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    L1 = "All", 
    L2 = "All"
  )

# Statistics by group
out_2 <- df %>%
  group_by(L1, L2) %>%
  summarize(
    mdn = median(scr),
    se = sd(scr) / sqrt(n())
  )

# Wilcoxon test
out_3 <- df %>%
  group_by(L1) %>%
  summarize(
    pv = wilcox.test(scr ~ L2)$p.value
  )

# Combine
out <- out_1 %>%
  bind_rows(out_2) %>%
  left_join(out_3)

       mdn         se        L1            L2        pv
1 0.750000 0.02702097       All           All        NA
2 0.750000 0.04224854 Age Class   Older Youth 0.5894851
3 0.671875 0.06034703 Age Class Younger Youth 0.5894851
4 0.828125 0.05615588    Gender        Female 0.6385921
5 0.781250 0.03125000    Gender          Male 0.6385921

If you're going to be doing this repeatedly, you could make a function out of it.
Or, if you want to do it all in one pipe and you're ok with the output being a slightly different format:
df %>%
  mutate(
    mdn_overall = median(scr),
    se_overall = sd(scr) / sqrt(n())
  ) %>%
  group_by(L1) %>%
  mutate(
    pv = wilcox.test(scr ~ L2)$p.value
  ) %>%
  group_by(L1, L2, mdn_overall, se_overall, pv) %>%
  summarize(
    mdn_group = median(scr),
    se_group = sd(scr) / sqrt(n())
  )

  L1        L2            mdn_overall se_overall    pv mdn_group se_group
  <chr>     <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Age Class Older Youth          0.75     0.0270 0.589     0.75    0.0422
2 Age Class Younger Youth        0.75     0.0270 0.589     0.672   0.0603
3 Gender    Female               0.75     0.0270 0.639     0.828   0.0562
4 Gender    Male                 0.75     0.0270 0.639     0.781   0.0312


Thanks a lot @ila for the effort. Luckily, I have found a solution & answered in the thread.

We can group it inside summarise and mutate with .by = ...  now. This seems to be a safer option for successive operations (IMHO). When use group_by, it's always a good idea to ungroup later or use summarise( .groups = ... ).

What I had in mind:
new_df <- df %>% 
  summarise(
    L1="All", L2="All", 
    mdn = median(scr), 
    se=(sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr)))) %>% 
  
  bind_rows(
    df %>% 
      summarise(
        .by = c(L1, L2), 
        mdn = median(scr), 
        se = (sd(scr)/sqrt(length(scr)))) %>% 
      
      left_join(
        df %>% 
          summarise(
            .by = L1,
            pv = wilcox.test(scr~L2)$p.value), 
        by = "L1"))

Output:
> new_df
         L1            L2      mdn         se        pv
1       All           All 0.750000 0.02702097        NA
2 Age Class   Older Youth 0.750000 0.04224854 0.5894851
3 Age Class Younger Youth 0.671875 0.06034703 0.5894851
4    Gender        Female 0.828125 0.05615588 0.6385921
5    Gender          Male 0.781250 0.03125000 0.6385921

